# Why was Miriam not allowed to enter the Promised Land?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, chukas, miriam

In Bamidbar 20:1 we read of the account of the death of Miriam. She being the oldest of the three siblings, Miriam, Aaron and Moshe, was she under the same judgement as the nation of Israel brought about by the report of the spies? Aaron and Moshe were not allowed to enter because they did not speak to the rock, but struck it; however, Miriam was not part of that mistake, so is there another explanation as to why she was not able to enter the land? (Other than as I previously stated that she fell under the same judgement as the cursed generation.)